# How to send Excel data to MySQL using pandas and PyMySQL?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I'm having issues importing data with python into a table on my Database directly from an excel file.

I have this code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

if os.path.exists("env.py"):
    import env
print(os.environ)


# Abre conexion con la base de datos
db = pymysql.connect(
    host = os.environ.get("MY_DATABASE_HOST"),
    user = os.environ.get("MY_USERNAME"),
    password = os.environ.get("MY_PASSWORD"),
    database = os.environ.get("MY_DATABASE_NAME")
)
##################################################

################LECTURA DE EXCEL##################
tabla_azul = "./excelFiles/tablaAzul.xlsx"
dAzul = pd.read_excel(tabla_azul, sheet_name='Órdenes')
dAzul.to_sql(con=db, name='tablaazul', if_exists='append', schema='str')
#print(type(dAzul))

tabla_verde = "./excelFiles/tablaVerde.xlsx"
dVerde = pd.read_excel(tabla_verde, sheet_name='Órdenes')
dVerde.to_sql(con=db, name='tablaverde', if_exists='append', schema='str')
```

1. I'm not sure what table name I have to put into the ***name*** variable.
2. Do I need to use *sqlalchemy* yes or yes?
3. If question 2 is yes: Is it possible to connect `sqlalchemy` with `pymysql`?
4. If question 3 is no: Ho do I use the .env variables like `host` with sqlalchemy connection?

thank you!

when I run the code above, it's giving me this error:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the pandas documentation, for any database other than SQLite [.to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) requires a SQLAlchemy `Connectable` object, which is either an `Engine` object or a `Connection` object. You can create an `Engine` object for PyMySQL like so:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create(
    "mysql+pymysql",
    username=os.environ.get("MY_USERNAME"),
    password=os.environ.get("MY_PASSWORD"),
    host=os.environ.get("MY_DATABASE_HOST"),
    database=os.environ.get("MY_DATABASE_NAME")
)
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)
```

Then you can call `.to_sql()` and pass it the `engine`:

```py
dVerde.to_sql(con=engine, name='tablaverde', if_exists='append', schema='str')
```